# Видимость переменной JS, AJAX, JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Обьясните пожалуйста почему переменная `song` в приведенном коде в функции `alert` равна `undefined`? При этом внутри блока `success` все ок. Правильно ли я понял, что для интерпретатора это две разных переменных? Скажите пожалуйста как сделать правильно.

```
function getTrackInfo(keys = null){

    var song;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/main/getTrackInformation',
        data: 'key=song&key2=title',
        dataType:'JSON',
        success: function (jsondata) {
            song = jsondata.song;
            $('#trackInformation').text(song);
        }

    });

     alert(song);
}
```

Comment: ибо `ajax` запрос выполняется асинхронно. Грубо говоря поток кода пошел дальше `alert()` а запрос пошел параллельно тому потоку. Это если в двух словах.

Comment: @Tsyklop какие есть варианты? Считывать `#trackInformation` ?

Comment: Переместить в строку после `success: function (jsondata) {`. И используйте `console.log(song);` - так круче :)

Comment: @Winteriscoming 1) сделать запрос не асинхронным. 2) сделать `callback` функцию которая будет ставить значение. Но у вас и сейчас все нормально. Просто перенесите `alert` в функцию `success`.

Comment: @TotalPusher это не для дебага. Я хочу просто понять почему так произошло. Первый ответ мне понятен, хочу теперь знать как быть если в будущем.

Comment: @Tsyklop мне нужно что бы в функции был return значения того что возвращает ajax. return song

Comment: @Winteriscoming тогда используй `Promise`-ы. Создай промис, в нем вызови `ajax` и когда вернется значение сделай `resolve(song)`. Сама функция `getTrackInfo` должна возвращать промис. Ну и потом получить значение `getTrackInfo().then(song=>{console.log(song)});`